# Automorphism Group of a p-group : Looking for a Reference

Tags: gr.group-theory, p-groups, finite-groups

In the following post by DavidLHarden :
[See Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68109/orders-of-automorphism-groups-of-p-groups)

He quoted the following claim:
"There is a theorem that says that if $p$ is  a prime and $|G|=p^n $ , then $|AutG| $ divides 
$ \Pi_{k=0}^{n-1} (p^{n}-p^{k}) $ " .

I can't find any reference for this theorem ,

Does someone know of any reference for this fact?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the theorem in this form may be due to Peter M. Neumann- so try Mathscinet if you have access- assuming the theorem is stated correctly.  It is certainly  true that ${\rm Aut}(G)$ has a normal $p$-subgroup whose index is bounded by the number you quote (this is a Theorem of W.Burnside).

Comment: I don't have Khukhro's book "$p$-Automorphisms of Finite $p$-Groups" here, but it would be a good place to try.

Comment: Geoff: I would try Mathscinet on Monday or something... I am not sure if this is due to Neumann or not... Thanks anyway! 

@mt: I couldn't find this theorem in the book you just mentioned...
Thanks for the suggestion! 


Answer (score 6):

I don't have a reference, but here's the next best thing: a proof.

First, let's fix some notation. Let $P$ be a p-group, $G$ it's group of automorphisms, and $\Phi(P) = P^p[P,P]$ it's Frattini subgroup. Define inductively $\Phi^k(P)$ as $\Phi(\Phi^{k-1}(P)).$

The subgroups $\Phi^k(P)$ form a decreasing chain of characteristic subgroups which exhaust $P.$

Let $$G_k := \ker(G \rightarrow Aut(P/\Phi^k(P)))$$
and
$$G_k' := \ker(G \rightarrow Aut(\Phi^k(P)/\Phi^{k+1}(P))).$$

Then the subgroups $G_k$ form an decreasing chain of normal subgroups of $G$ which exhaust $G.$

Let $d_k = \dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\Phi^k(P)/\Phi^{k+1}(P)).$ The group $P$ can be generated by $d_0$ elements. Choose a generating set $g_1 ... g_{d_0}$ and consider the map from $G_k \cap G_k'/G_{k+1}$ to $(\Phi^k(P)/\Phi^{k+1}(P))^{d_0}$

given by

$$\sigma \mapsto (\sigma(g_i)g_i^{-1})_{i=1}^{d_0}.$$

This map is an injective group homomorphism.

On the other hand $G_k/(G_{k} \cap G_{k}')$ injects into  $Aut(\Phi^k(P)/\Phi^{k+1}(P)) \cong GL_{d_i}( \mathbb{F}_p).$

Note that if $p^n = |P|$ and $r = max\{d_i : d_i \neq 0\},$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^r d_i = n.$ It follows that the order $$|G| = \displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{r}|G_k/G_{k+1}| = \displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{r} |(G_k \cap G_k')/G_{k+1}||(G_k \cap G_k')/G_{k+1}|$$ divides

$$\displaystyle\prod_{s=0}^{d_0-1} (p^{d_0} - p^s)\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{r} p^{d_kd_0}\displaystyle\prod_{s=0}^{d_k-1} (p^{d_k} - p^s)$$

which divides

$$\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (p^n - p^k).$$

Comment: Note that it is completely pointless to put \displaystyle (on outer bracing level) into displayed equations (they are already set in display style), and even more pointless to put more than one of these in one formula (the first declaration remains in effect). Judging from the usage, you may be confusing \displaystyle with \limits.

Comment: Thanks @JSpecter! 
I'll go over your proof later today...
The problem is that a friend of mine needs this fact for a paper he's writing, and I don't think a proof of a known fact is something that he would want to put in his paper (due to copyrighting rights) 

Thanks anyway
! 

Comment: @Mraz, it isn't anything to do with copyright.  However, you are right that it's best to cite a published paper if it exists.

Comment: @JSpecter.  Since $\prod(p^n-p^k)$ is the order of GL$(n,p)$, I'm wondering if Aut$(G)$ is in fact isomorphic to some subgroup of GL$(n,p)$. Is it a silly thought?

Comment: @McKay, when $p>2$, the automorphism group of a cyclic group of order $p^3$ contains elements of order $p^2$, but $GL(3,p)$ does not. 

Comment: Why is a reference considered preferable to a proof? A proof is what you want to find in the reference.

Comment: @DavidLHarden: But you don't want to prove something that is well known in a paper you are writing... By proving it, it's kind of saying that you are the one that figured this theorem out...

But if you already saw this post... Have you got any idea for possible reference? In your first message I quoted, you said that it's well known, do you know where can I find it  ? 

Thanks ! 


Comment: There is some material that is pretty close to a proof of this (it contains most, if not all, of the elements of the proof) in Marshall Hall Jr.'s "Theory of Finite Groups".

Comment: @JSpecter You have obtained a very weak result in so complicated way. For an easier proof, see any textbook containing sections devoted finite p-groups..

Answer (score 5):

As @DavidLHarden explains in the link that you gave, this theorem is proved by attending to the $p$-part and $p'$-part separately.

For the $p'$-part the result follows from the following theorem of Burnside:

> Let $\psi$ be a $p'$-automorphism of the $p$-group $P$ which induces the identity on $P/\Phi(P)$. Then $\psi$ is the identity automorphism of $P$.

This is the result that Geoff refers to in his comment above. It is discussed and proved in Section 5 of Gorenstein's *Finite Groups*, specifically Theorem 1.4 of that section.

I do not know of a reference for the $p$-part of the proof. You should certainly look at [the paper by Neumann that Geoff mentions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hd5ryzqt8u5g27h/Neumann%20Proof%20of%20a%20conjecture.pdf), however if I understand that proof correctly it only proves your bound for $|Out P|$, rather than $|Aut P|$. On the other hand Neumann is considering a much more general setting than just $p$-groups.

Comment: @Nick Gill: Thanks ! Sorry for my ignorance, but what is the $p'$ part of the result? (I can't understand what is $p'$ in your response) . 
I also have trouble getting into the link you just gave... It gives me an error... can you please fix it? 

Thanks ! 


Comment: @Jason, I've fixed the link. Sorry about that. You can split this bound into two parts: prove that the biggest power of p dividing Aut G divides the given product, and then prove that the biggest integer coprime to p dividing Aut G divides the given product. When I write the p'-part I mean the latter.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, if $|G|=p^n$ and $d(G)=d$, then
$|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$ divides the number $$(p^n-p^{n-d})(p^n-p^{n-d+1}) ... (p^n-p^{n-1}).$$ This result is due to P. Hall (1933)

Proof. The above product is the number of minimal bases of $G$. However, that number is a multiple of $|\text{Aut}(G)|$. Indeed, if $\cal B$ is the set of all bases of $G$, then all $\text{Aut}(G)$-orbits on $\cal B$ have the same cardinality $|\text{Aut}(G)|$.

Comment: Could you add a more precise reference, please?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually easy to put a bound on $Aut(P)$ for some finite $p$-group $P$, simply using Burnside's basis theorem, which says every basis for the elementary abelian group $P/\Phi(P)$ corresponds to a minimal generating set for the group $P$.  Clearly, any element of $Aut(P)$ must take one minimal generating set to another.

So how many minimal generating sets are there? Well, if $|\Phi(P)| = p^d$, and $|P/\Phi(P)|=p^e$, then a minimal generating set consists of $e$ elements.  There are
$$ \prod_{k=0}^{e-1} (p^e-p^k) $$
different bases of $P/\Phi(P)$ (as a vector space of dimension $e$). Each such element really represents a *coset* of $\Phi(P)$, which contains $p^d$ elements; that is, for such a given basis, *each* basis vector has $p^d$ choices up in $P$; all told, then, there are
$$ p^{de} \prod_{k=0}^{e-1} (p^e-p^k) $$

minimal generating sets. Of course, $Aut(P)$ acts on these freely (as it is defined by what it does to a generating set), so its order divides that number.

Answer (score 0):

In post 6 is presented a weak result (it attained only for elementary abelian $P$). The Hall's result in post 3 is attained by many groups. It may be improved only in the case if we have an additional information on $P$.